# htaccess rewrite example.com/user.php?id=username to example.com/username

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Title says it all im having trouble rewriting the following urls

The original URL:
`example.com/user.php?id=username`

The rewritten URL:
`example.com/username`

My `.htcacess` code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /user.php?id=$1 [L]
```

What the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite engine will loop, which means the rewritten URI (`/user.php`) matches the same pattern and gets applied again. Try adding some conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /user.php?id=$1 [L]
```